# What is the requirement to turn an element into droppable area

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm wondering what is considered a valid droppable area in drag&drop API in HTML5.
I've read several articles and in each the requirements are different:

- should have at lease three event handlers: `dragenter`, `dragover` and `drop`
- should have `draggable=true` attribute
- should match mime type set by `dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", data)`
- should have `dropzone` attribute

Which of these are required? Are there any other requirements?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

First of all: To make an element draggable, set the **draggable** attribute to true:

`<img draggable="true">`

The **dataTransfer.setData()** method sets the data type and the value of the dragged data:

Then, specify what should happen when the element is dragged.

In the example above, the **ondragstart** attribute calls a function, drag(event), that specifies what data to be dragged.

The **dataTransfer.setData()** method sets the data type and the value of the dragged data:

```
function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
```

In this case, the data type is "text" and the value is the id of the draggable element ("drag1").

The **ondragover** event specifies where the dragged data can be dropped.

By default, data/elements cannot be dropped in other elements. To allow a drop, we must prevent the default handling of the element.

This is done by calling the **event.preventDefault()** method for the ondragover event:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

When the dragged data is dropped, a drop event occurs.

In the example above, the ondrop attribute calls a function, drop(event):

```
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }
```